# performing operations on columns and rows

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I have TWO tables

1) column

2) row

```
COLUMN TABLE                
COLumnID
----------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

ROW TABLE
ROW iD
-------------
100
104
101
99
77
20
10
```

The final output should look like this:

```
01.Row         1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
02.----------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
03.10          x    x              x                  
04.20          x    x         x    x                  
05.77          x                             x        
06.99          x         x                             x
07.100         x    x         x    x                  
08.101         x                                      
09.104         x    x         x                   x
```

The challenge is to mark a coordinate, with a value of X, if and only if the row value is divisible by the col value, i.e. it has a modulo of zero. The additional requirements are: the final query must work with random row values and the pivot operator should be used.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? It looks familiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you are looking for in sql server.
use a CTE to determine where the x should be and then pivot from that CTE

```
with mq as(select a.rowid
                ,b.columnid
                ,case when (a.rowid % b.columnid) = 0 then 'X' else null end as coord
           from row_table a
                inner join column_table b on 1=1)

select  rowid,[1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
from mq
pivot( max(coord) for columnid in ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9])) as pv
```